# java.lang.NullPointerException: null when I call a repository

Tags: java, spring-boot, autowired

Good afternoon, what I try to do here is to validate if there is an object through the CUSPP that would become my ID, but this validation is done outside my @Controller, therefore I want to do it in my AffiliateActiveV and then call it through `AfiliadoActivoV obj = new AfiliadoActivoV()`then fill it with the data `AfiliadoActivoV(cuspp)`.

I need validations done outside of my @Controller class because SonarLint tells me that the class is getting too big.

AfiliadoActivoRepository

```
@Repository
public interface AfiliadoActivoRepository extends CrudRepository<AfiliadoActivoEntity, String> {
}
```

AfiliadoActivoController

```
@RestController
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
public class CargaArchivoController {
        @GetMapping(path = "/leertxt")
    public @ResponseBody String leerArchivo() {
        AfiliadoActivoV obj = new AfiliadoActivoV();
       return obj.validacionCampos(item.cuspp) //This value comes from a reading made to a csv file - I have validated with a System.out.Print and if it has data
    }
}
```

AfiliadoActivoV

```
public class AfiliadoActivoV {

    @Autowired
    AfiliadoActivoRepository crudAfiliadoActivo2;

public String validacionCampos(String cuspp) {
    String respuesta="";
    if(crudAfiliadoActivo2.existsById(cuspp)==true) {
         respuesta= respuesta + " Error: CUSPP Duplicado";
    }
}}
```

I attached the error that appears in the console of the STS
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/woxOL.png)

Comment: Can you post your spring configuration where you launch your app from and anything related to how your repositories are setup. Make sure that spring knows of the packages to look at for components.

Comment: How are you using `AfiliadoActivoV`?

Comment: I am using AffiliateActiveV to be able to validate different fields before performing a crud.save (object) but for this I need to perform the function existsById in a class external to @Controller

Comment: I think `cuspp` is null that is cause you get `NullPointerExcpetion`

Comment: Where do you `@EnableJpaRepositories`?

Comment: I will add more code to my project so that it can be better understood.

Comment: @RenzoLlagas, "I am using AffiliateActiveV to be able"... that doesn't say how are you using it still. Is it a Spring component/bean? Your posted code seems to say it's not, which means nothing gets autowired.

Comment: Exactly, in the AffiliateActiveV class I only use @Autowired, I'm new to SpringBoot, do you need any other tags to connect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fact that it's just a null-pointer tells you that Spring didn't even try to find a bean to inject here. Spring would tell you if it tried injecting the @Autowired but could not find a matching bean.

This means that `AfiliadoActivoV` is not picked up by Springs Component-Scanning which collects all the CDI-able classes.

1. Annotate your class with `@Component` or `@Service`

   ```
   @Component
   public class AfiliadoActivoV {
   ```
2. Make sure the class can be found during component scanning.
   If you rely on annotation based configuration, you have a class which is annotated with `@SpringBootApplication`. By default SpringBoot will only scan this directory and ALL SUBDIRECTORIES for Bean-classes.

I suppose your `@SpringBootApplication`-class is located in a sub- or sibling-directory of `AfiliadoActivoV`.

In this case you can either modify your class-structure or use `@ComponentScan("...")`